# how to get mic volume in ios 7?

Tags: ios, volume, ios7

there a view to get mic volume in ios 7?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

NSError *error;

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

if (recorder) {
    //recorder.delegate = self;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = TRUE;
    [recorder record];
    levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
} else {
    NSLog(@"");// mic error message
}

- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [recorder updateMeters];

    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (ALPHA * [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0]));
    db = 20* log10(peakPowerForChannel);
    db += taraturaDb;
    db = db < 0 ? 0 : db;
    lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;

    if (lowPassResults < 0.95) {
        NSLog(@"%f",db);
}
```

this that worked in iOS6 doesn't work in iOS 7

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put these lines before you initialize AVAudioRecorder:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
```

Comment: This is great, except it broke my other sound effects :/

Comment: @FaddishWorm Set the audio session category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`. "This category is appropriate for simultaneous recording and playback, and also for apps that record and play back but not simultaneously" as per [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories)

Comment: Anyone know if this can also safely be used in iOS 6 and lower?